# Firefox image selection color

Tags: css, firefox

I changed the selection color of the text with this CSS:

```
::-moz-selection {
    background: #D9230F;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
::selection {
    background: #D9230F;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

But the image selection color in Firefox is still blue. How can I change that?

---

### [image: img]

**EDIT:** I want the image to be *selectable*, so `user-select: none` doesn't help me.

Comment: @hungerstar It says there that I should use `user-select: none`, which prevents selecting the image completely. But I want the image to be selectable.

Comment: @hungerstar: That's not changing the color of the highlight, that's removing the highlight altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the image selection color in Firefox (yet). A bug has been opened here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1084708

If this is really important to you, I suggest to contribute to that bug report, since the guys at Mozilla don't seem to give it too much importance - it still has an UNCONFIRMED status even though it's reported in 2014.

Comment: Considering the current state of ::selection I doubt they're very motivated to work on it. ::selection has been a pain point for over half a decade, [and for a very good reason](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#highlight-pseudos).